# Calling YouTube iFrame Javascript API YT.Player.stopVideo shows black screen

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

guys, I'm trying to stop some YouTube with iFrame Javascript API. I found some strange thing, that is when I call YT.Player.stopVideo() to stop the play, the video stops playing, but shows some black screen. What I expect is to show the poster image or the video frame where it is stopped rather than some black screen.

I've written some test in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ekv2jufo/), as you can see that once the video gets loaded, click stop button the player windows shows black screen. Any suggestions for achieving what I expected?

```
<script>
    function stopNow() {
        g_ytPlayer.stopVideo();
    }
</script>
<div>
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/V_7zfVwlIUI?wmode=transparent&amp;rel=0&amp;controls=2&amp;showinfo=0&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;autoplay=1&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http://fiddle.jshell.net" id="yt-iframe-10017" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0">         </iframe>
</div>
<p>
<span>Please wait for the video loading complete to stop</span><br/>
<button onclick="stopNow();">Stop</button>
</p>
```